# Unable to file multiple BLOB to Synapse using data factory

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I want to copy bulk data from BLOB storage to Azure Synapse with the following structure:

**BLOB STORAGE:-**

```
devpresented (Storage account)
        processedout (Container)
                Merge_user (folder)
                    > part-00000-tid-89051a4e7ca02.csv
                Sales_data (folder)
                    > part-00000-tid-5579282100a02.csv
```

**SYNAPSE SQLDW:**

```
SCHEMA:- PIPELINEDEMO
TABLE: Merge_user, Sales_data
```

Using data factory I want to copy BLOB data to Synapse database as below:

```
BLOB        >>  SQLDW
Merge_user  >>  PIPELINEDEMO.Merge_user
Sales_data  >>  PIPELINEDEMO.Sales_data
```

The following doc in mentioned for SQL DB to SQL DW:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-bulk-copy-portal

However, I didn't find anything for BLOB source in data facory.

Can anyone please suggest, how can I move multiple BLOB files to different tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to copy the contents of different csv files to different tables in Azure Synapse, then you can enable multiple copy activities within a pipeline.

I create a .csv file, this is the content:

```
111,222,333,
444,555,666,
777,888,999,
```

I upload this to my storage account, Then I set this .csv file as the source of the copy activity.

[image]

After that, I create a table in azure synapse, and set this as the sink of the copy activity:

```
create table testbowman4(Prop_0 int, Prop_1 int, Prop_2 int)
```

[image]

At last, trigger this pipeline, you will find the data is in the table:

[image]

You can create multiple similar copy activities, and each copy activity performs a copy action from blob to azure synapse.